# maven multiple modules reference through mvn site

Tags: java, maven

This is the structure of my project:

```
aokshop
    -- aokshop-core
    -- aokshop-admin
    -- aokshop-service
    -- pom.xml
```

And then I run with command: `mvn site`

It generate a "site" folder in parent aokshop and every children modules,  then I open the "index.html" file in aokshop, it likes that:
[image]

It lists all the modules. But I can't open the children modules,

`file:///G:/workspace/aokshop/target/site/aokshop-admin/index.html`

It can't find, I have used the maven-jxr-plugin and config it like:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <reportSets>
    <reportSet>
      <id>aggregate</id>
      <reports>
        <report>aggregate</report>
        <report>test-aggregate</report>
      </reports>
    </reportSet>
  </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

So can I do that I can reference the children modules in parent "index.html".

Answer (score 0):

[An excerpt from the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html):

> Note that links between module sites in a multi module build will not
>   work, since local build directory structure doesn't match deployed
>   site.

This means you need to do a staging to check you links and the whole layout etc. This can be achieved by using the [`stage` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html).